# What is mongodb logging as a COMMAND?

Tags: mongodb

Relating to mongodb's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#COMMAND), database commands such as `count` will be logged as component COMMAND. However neither `db.count()` nor `db.runCommand({count:'mycollection'})` produces a COMMAND log entry, even if the default log level for COMMAND is raised from 0 to 1.
Dropping an index, a collection or a database produces a COMMAND log entry even with the default log level 0 though.

Moreover, it seems that almost all mongodb actions can be expressed as command (even a `find`), as shown in mongodb's [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/), so I wonder how one could properly differentiate between [QUERY](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/#QUERY) which logs messages related to queries and COMMANDs.

My goal is to filter out (administrative) commands from the logs for auditing (and I don't want to use mongodb's enterprise version with auditing functionalities for this single purpose).
I'm using mongodb version 4.0.5 Linux 64Bit.

Thanks for shedding light on this!

Answer (score 0):

After setting the verbosity level for `command` as 1, I am able to see the following entries in the log file

> 2019-03-01T16:25:56.967-0800 I COMMAND  [conn67] command test.icons
>   appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: count { count: "icons",
>   $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "test" }
>   planSummary: COUNT keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 numYields:0 reslen:45
>   locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount:
>   { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } }
>   protocol:op_command 0ms

here the collection name is `icons` and the database is `test`

I used the following command to increase the verbosity level.

```
db.setLogLevel(1, "command")
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's being logged when the log level is raised from 0 to 1. I must have overseen it due to so many `acquireCount`log entries which arises when the log level is raised to 1. The log becomes rapidly polluted by so many messages. Even `find` operations are logged then, since it's a command under the hood which leads me to my former question, how one could properly differentiate between QUERY which logs messages related to queries and COMMANDs.

Comment: Try mlogfilter , which will help you to filter log messages

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-mtools